# Delete DB record from SQlite using PHP Tinker

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel

while adding a user in PHP artisan tinker on laracasts/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/10, I accidentally typed `$username->username = 'JohnDoe';` instead of `$user->username = 'JohnDoe';` So the $username does not exist and is, therefore causing an issue when trying to save a user. How do I find $username and delete it? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how that would affect anything because `$username` would have had to have been defined as some other instance of `App\User` before it would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a small enough users table, which I am assuming you do because you're running through Jeffrey's tutorials, I'd do something like this to track down that bad row.

`App\User::all()`, find the `id` of the User you want to delete, then run `App\User::find(<THE ID OF THE ONE TO DELETE>)->delete();`

Comment: Thanks, is there any documentation specifically handling databases in Tinker? I couldn't find much online. Cheers

Comment: Just think of Tinker as being a PHP file that you execute line-by-line. Anything you can write in your Model files you can write in Tinker. If you are looking for something to use as far as checking out your database entries from a high level, I'd recommend the program [SequelPro](http://www.sequelpro.com/)